# Ajax call from Angular's $http causing memory leak (with closures)

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, google-chrome, coffeescript

I'm having memory leak issues in my AJAX calls. I am doing so ...
(You can reproduce the problem with this example)

```
 $scope.mouseClickBlue= () ->
   $($scope.getProjects)

 $scope.getProjects = () ->
   $http.post("/phoenix/rest/projects", { 1 : "1234", 2 : "" }).success (projects) ->
     console.log projects
```

And i call with ng-click="mouseClickBlue()".

Looking at the Chrome's 43.0.2357.130m task manager, I see the tab memory consumption only grow every time I click at the button and dont stop grow up.

At the and of day, the tab have 400.000K of memory usage.

I tryed set null to parameter "projects" too, but not work.

The Angular version is: 1.2.15

It's a Chrome's bug or my code is incorrect?

Comment: Could it be because you're constantly logging to the console, the contents of which is then retained in the memory of the Chrome process?

Comment: I put the console only for to example, but I test this code with NOTHING inside the callback and the memory continues grow up.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Chrome is generally a memory hog, which is being addressed in newer versions. I don't think that looking at the memory consumption is a solid indicator of a memory leak in your AngularJS application.